# GCC: Auto dependency generation not working for assembler files / inline assembler

Tags: gcc, makefile

I’m using the toolchain GNUARM-NONE v16.01 with manually written makefile. I use the gcc option to automatically create the file depencencies (e.g. if .h file is changed all the corresponding .c files will be compiled). Commands for the dependency file generation:

```
# Create c file dependencies
@$(CC) -MM -MP -MF “$(DEP_FILE)” -MT”$(OBJ_FILE)” -MT”$(DEP_FILE)” @”$(CC_OPTIONS)” “$<”
(gcc called with -x c)

# Create assembler file dependencies
@$(CC) -MM -MP -MF “$(DEP_FILE)” -MT”$(OBJ_FILE)” -MT”$(DEP_FILE)” @”$(ASM_OPTIONS)” “$<”
(gcc called with -x assembler)
```

Unfortunately this works only for header files. If I have a .c file with inline assembler that includes itselfs an assembler include file (.inc), changing that .inc file doesn’t lead to recompilation of the .c file:

```
void test ()
{
  asm volatile ( “.include \”test.inc\” \n\t”
  .. do some asm stuff here   );
}
```

In assembler file .asm the inc files are included using the .include directive. Changing the .inc file doesn’t lead to recompilation of the asm file. If I change the .include directive to #include and compile with “-x assembler-with-cpp” then changing the .inc file leads to recompilation of the .asm file. But the problem with the inline assembler remains, I cannot use the #include directive there.

So it seems that the auto dependency creation works only for standard c and the #include directive but not for assembler and the .include directive.

Or how do I use the auto dependency generation also for the assembler code/files?

Comment: Maybe the hints at https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/MD.html#MD can help you. I don't know how that translates to the gcc options, though.

Comment: Calling `as --MD` for the assembler files resolves the problem. Thus, as cannot be called anymore via gcc, which is the standard case.

But the problem with the inline assembly remains, gcc is not able to resolve the dependencies when using `.include` in inline assembly.

Comment: Out of pure interest: did you try to [pass the option to the assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Assembler-Options.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried passing the option to the assembler, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: A last proposal: can you compile via the assembler and do a postprocessing of the generated assembler files, extracting depency information? You know that you only need to update the dependencies AFTER you compiled, do you?

Comment: I managed to call the `as` via the `gcc` with the `--MD option`, dependency generation works only for the assembler files.
The problem with the inline assembly in the c files remains, `gcc` just doesn't support the `.include` directive. I cannot compile the c files using `as`, so this one particular problems remains. The `#include` directive is not supported in inline assembly, `gcc` ends with error. So no workaround without changes in `gcc`.